# Django user permision on Update object

Tags: django, object, permissions, modelform

The work flow is listed below

- user post something. the initial status of the post is unpublished(is_published=False)
- admin approve the post. so post status is published(is_published= True)
- when the post status is published(is_published= True) user is not
  able to edit post.
- user to be able to edit, the post need to be unpublished(is_published=False). Then user is able to edit post. Require admin approval again.

```py
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # adminn start here
        if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
            obj = post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.submitted = obj.submitted
                post.save()
                return redirect(approved_post)
            else:
                print("form invalid. post. admin")
                # admin end here
        #user star here
        else:
            obj = post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
            # check post status. if published cant edit
            if obj.is_published:
                print("no permission . user")
                return redirect(approved_post)  # error page here
            else:
                if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.submitted = request.user
                    post.save()
                    return redirect(approved_post)
                else:
                    print("form invalid. post. user")

    # GET
    else:
        obj = post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        # checking is user is admin or normal user
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            #checking if post is belong to the logged in user
            if obj.submitted == request.user:
                form = PostForm(instance=obj)
            else:
                print("not your object")
        else:
            form = PostForm(instance=obj)
    return render(request, 'post/edit_post.html', {'form': form})
```

My concern is there any better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is object-level permission. For a single use case you can write the logic yourself, but I highly recommend using an external package.

There are two well-known and maintained packages for this:

- [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules)
- [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian)

I believe django-rules suits your case best and will be very simple to implement. Let me know if you need an example.